# How to fetch and display image in ReactJS, that is returned from web API

Tags: reactjs, image, asp.net-core-webapi

How to fetch and display image in reactJS, that is returned from asp.net core web API.

ReactJS:
I can see the image is returned from API in the dev console.

```
  this.state = {                     
       text: "Hello", // the text for which code need to be generated
       result: '',
    };

}
```

Below code has no problem until 'response.ok' line. But does not get past 'response.json'.

```
async componentDidMount() {
      await GenQRCode(this.state.text).then(
        (response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json() // removing response.json and setting response.url below solved the issue
                    .then((response) => {                           
                        this.setState({ result: response });
                    });
            }
        })          
}
```

I could display QRCode in my component, if I manually copy the URL of QRCode from preview section of dev tool and set the state of 'result' with that URL.

```
<p><img src={this.state.result} height = "200" width = "200" /></p>
```

Comment: maybe your response body is not a JSON format response, try to console.log response.body?

Comment: Above code has no problem until 'response.ok' line. But does not get past 'response.json'. So as you were mentioning, would it be because image is not returned in response.json format?

Comment: Just want to add that you could use the url as source to an image and be done?

Comment: I was able to rectify by using response.url as above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setImage(responseAsBlob) {
  const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(responseAsBlob);  
  return imgUrl;
}

const response = await fetchAPI('YOUR URL');

if (response) {
this.setState({result:setImage(await response.blob())});
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you suggest me how do I fetch my URL programmatically here 'const response = await fetchAPI('YOUR URL')'.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion as above. Please refer code. I am using class based components. When I add this "const response = await fetchAPI('YOUR URL');" it says const modifier can only be used in typescript files.

Comment: const response = await fetchAPI('YOUR URL');   
Hey.. this is just a algorithm, use your FEtch API instead
REFER this for fetch syntax
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: Thank you.  Above code has no problem until 'response.ok' line. But does not get past 'response.json'.

Comment: check what are you getting in response, I think it will be response.data
Also, I think you should change your API end slightly and check with StreamResponse

Comment: I was able to rectify by using response.url as above. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add more information than just a code answer. The goal here is to help people learn the "why" as well as just the solution.